# Is it possible to classify points on a 2D surface according to their tangent planes?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose we have a 2D compact closed smooth surface in $\Bbb R^3$. And for any plane, there are at most 3 points on the surface tangent to  it.

So the question is that can we classify the points on the surface into 3 sets $A, B, C$, which are pairwise disjoint and the union is the entire surface, such that every set is a connected set and any 2 points in the same set won't share a common tangent plane?

Comment: Consider the embedding of a torus as the surface of revolution of a circle. Lay a plane "on top of" the torus, then this plane is tangent to a circle of points, not 3 points.

Comment: @DavidSheard : Yes, but such surfaces are excluded from our consideration. We only care about surfaces meeting above condition.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry. Your wording made me think you thought that condition held for all surfaces